# Python / Django / Apache2/ WSGI / UserDir / Conda: Django

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, conda

I want to run 2 django applications on a linux server (Debian). These two project run well on my pc and on the server using the django command `runserver`. Here is what I did so far:

I activated userdir:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

I created two users:

```
sudo useradd -g www-data -m user1
sudo useradd -g www-data -m user2su
```

Then I created my two conda environments, imported from a file, with the same name as my users. I created two directories where I put my django projects `/var/www/users/user1` and `/var/www/users/user2`.

Then I create a conf file for each user:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/user1.conf
```

with the following content

```
WSGIDaemonProcess user1 user=user1 home=/var/www/users/user1 processes=1 threads=3 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/www/users/user1 python-home=/home/developer/anaconda3/envs/user1/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /~user1 /var/www/users/user1/user1/user1/wsgi.py process-group=user1
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<Directory /var/www/users/user1>
        WSGIProcessGroup user1
</Directory>
```

`developer` is the user that is used for development on the server.
I also add these lines to my apache2.conf file:

```
UserDir disabled
UserDir enabled user1 user2
UserDir /var/www/users
<Directory /var/www/users>
AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
Options +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI -Includes -Indexes
AddHandler wsgi-script wsgi
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried to install wsgi with the package manager or directly from source in the corresponding conda environment. I always get the following error:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

A bit above:

```
mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
```

Do you have an idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the best success by reading the mod_wsgi documents. There can be many issues for why the Apache/Python does not communicate, and the mod_wsgi documents by Graham Dumpleton are the best resource.

[modwsgi readthedocs install](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installation.html)

You really need to take the time to study how to install the mod_wsgi for the target operating system.